# pexpect - multiple expects

Tags: python, pexpect

Is it possible to "wait" for different answers from an `expect` command at the same time?

E.g: `child.expect('first', 'second')`

And if YES, how can differentiate which one has triggered it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like:

```
i = child.expect(['first', 'second'])
```

The expect() method returns the index of the pattern that was matched. So in your example:

```
if i == 0:
    # do something with 'first' match
else: # i == 1
    # do something with 'second' match
```

For more: http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/overview.html

Comment: Is there anyway to do this where you have multiple options? As in what if you want to execute both the first and second option?

Comment: @M.Barbieri: Yes, this becomes a programming question. When there are multiple options, you can do like, `i = child.expect (['option1', 'option2', 'option3']); if i in [0, 1]:  do something for first 2 options...`