# How to monitor child's output before promt?

Tags: python, subprocess, pexpect

Here is an example code of a slow application. (Imagine the boot of a Linux) This is the DUT, which should be controlled.

```py
#linux.py

import time

print('Loading kernel ......')
time.sleep(0.5)
print('Loading foo  [  OK  ]')
time.sleep(0.5)
print('Loading bar  [  OK  ]')
time.sleep(0.5)
input('login> ')
```

I want to control via [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html) python script like the following.

```py
# controller.py

import pexpect
import sys

pybin = sys.executable

command = pybin + ' linux.py' 

p = pexpect.spawn(command)
p.expect('> ', timeout = 5)
print(p.before.decode(), end='')
print(p.match.group(0).decode())
p.sendline('')
```

It is OK, but I cannot get the console's output of the *"Linux.py's"* boot before total boot-up. I mean, I didn't get feedback before the login prompt. Imagine, there is an error during the boot-up. The script above will fail with timeout exception.

**My GOAL**

To monitor the child process and print it's output while waiting to prompt. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

I found an easy way based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35132976/2506522) question

```py
# controller.py

import pexpect
import sys

pybin = sys.executable

command = pybin + ' linux.py' 

p = pexpect.spawn(command)
while True:
    # The return value is the index of the matched string
    i=p.expect(['> ', '\n'], timeout = 5)
    print(p.before.decode(), end='')
    print(p.match.group(0).decode(), end='')
    if i==0:
        break
print()
p.sendline('')
```

The key is to wait on multiple *"expected string"*. Then decide which is the real prompt and which is the line end. This solution works if the error is terminated with a newline character.

**Solution 2**

Other way is to use small timeout and print the proper chunk of the before string:

```py
# controller.py

import pexpect
import sys

pybin = sys.executable

command = pybin + ' linux.py' 

p = pexpect.spawn(command)
timeout_cnt = 0
print_idx = 0
while True:
    try:
        i=p.expect('> ', timeout = 1)
        # prompt has arrived
        break
    except pexpect.TIMEOUT:
        timeout_cnt += 1
        if timeout_cnt>30:
            # A real timeout has occured
            raise
    finally:        
        print(p.before.decode()[print_idx:], end='')
        print_idx = len(p.before.decode())
print(p.match.group(0).decode(), end='')
print()
p.sendline('')
```